# Raspberry Pi Zero W Semi Freeze

Tags: pi-zero-w, raspicam, motion

I want to use motion (https://motion-project.github.io) to stream video on a remote location with internet connection using the raspi-cam V2 on a raspberry pi zero w. Besides stream, the idea is also make timelapse or shots and upload the files to a server. I am aware that when implementing the idea on a other computer I would run into less problems, I am currently also testing on a Odroid C2.

After some days pi crashed after some days, I found this threat:https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=212777. So I added `over_voltage=6` . I though this would solve the problem but after 7 days, the pi went *numb*. I was still able to log in using  `ssh`  and use  `top`  but other things did not work, even `ls` . After writing down a command and pressing enter nothing happend, but you were still able to log in using another window. The motion stream was also down. I could not even restart. I let it on a couple of days to see if the system would recover, but nothing. see image.

[image: Top after 11 days]

Does someone has also experience this behaviour? I has already happy that the pi is still accessible, but I has not able to do anything. I unplugged the pi and set `over_voltage=4`  to see what happens, will have to wait some days again.

UPDATE:

The output of `dmesg` when the system freezes is as follow:

[1691678.165092] bcm2835-v4l2: vidioc_s_fmt_vid_cap: failed to setup mmal components: -62
[1691681.205048] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: timed out waiting for sync completion
[1691684.245052] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: timed out waiting for sync completion
[1691684.245101] bcm2835-v4l2: vidioc_s_fmt_vid_cap: failed to setup mmal components: -62
[1691691.925084] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: timed out waiting for sync completion
[1691694.965233] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: timed out waiting for sync completion

Comment: loadavg 153!!! that's crazy!!!! what's the output of `dmesg`

Comment: It is now up 2 days,  1:34,  1 user,  load average: 0.09, 0.18, 0.18. The only thing I see in red from `dmesg` is from `brcmfmac`, the last message from it is: `brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled`

Comment: well, I'd wait until it "freezes" with a loadavg of anything above 10, then do a dmesg